# CGContext & CGMutablePath drawing line But it's be reversed

Tags: ios, swift, cgcontext

I use CgContext & CGMutablePath to Draw objects but the image that drawed  be reversed.
I need Draw Object to CoreMl drawing classification project.

I use Touchs events to draw object 
But when I draw to top direction if will be to bottom direction.
I want the line is correct direction

I learn from [link](https://github.com/apple/turicreate/blob/master/userguide/drawing_classifier/export-coreml.md)

```
func drawContextLine(from fromPoint: CGPoint, to toPoint:CGPoint) ->CGImage?{

        let grayscale = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray()
        if contextDraw == nil{
            contextDraw = CGContext(
            data:nil, width:256, height:256, bitsPerComponent:8, bytesPerRow:0,
            space:grayscale, bitmapInfo:CGImageAlphaInfo.none.rawValue)
        }

        //        intermediate_bitmap_context?.setStrokeColor(
        //            red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
        contextDraw?.setStrokeColor(UIColor.white.cgColor)

        let path = CGMutablePath()
        path.move(to: fromPoint)
        path.addLine(to: toPoint)

        contextDraw?.setLineWidth(5.0)
        contextDraw?.beginPath()
        contextDraw?.addPath(path)
        contextDraw?.strokePath()

        guard let imgCg = contextDraw?.makeImage() else {
            return nil
        }
        imgViewPridict.image = UIImage.init(cgImage: imgCg)
        return contextDraw?.makeImage()

    }
```

touch begin

```
  override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
          if let touch = touches.first{
              lastPoint = touch.location(in: self.view)

          }
    }
```

touch move

```
   override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        guard touches.first != nil else {
            return
        }
        if let touch = touches.first {

            let currentPoint = touch.location(in: self.view)
            drawLine(from: lastPoint, to: currentPoint)
            drawContextLine(from: lastPoint, to: currentPoint)
            lastPoint = currentPoint
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you want the drawing to be reversed? Or are you saying that your drawing is getting reversed? It’s not clear in the question.

Comment: Sorry for that, My drawing is getting reversed, . I need it correct direction. thanks

Comment: Your drawContextLine function is returning a CGImage. Are you drawing that image into another view? Or the drawing in the image itself is reversed?

Comment: No. I'm not draw in another view, it's return CGImage because I need it in CoreML detection . Can you try draw an example object use that?

Comment: Added a snippet as an answer. Do try and accept if it is helpful. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the code snippet below.

```
func drawContextLine(from fromPoint: CGPoint, to toPoint:CGPoint) ->CGImage?{

        let grayscale = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray()
        if contextDraw == nil{
            contextDraw = CGContext(
            data:nil, width:256, height:256, bitsPerComponent:8, bytesPerRow:0,
            space:grayscale, bitmapInfo:CGImageAlphaInfo.none.rawValue)
        }

        contextDraw?.setStrokeColor(UIColor.white.cgColor)

        contextDraw?.saveGState()
        contextDraw?.translateBy(x: 0, y: CGFloat(integerLiteral: contextDraw?.height ?? 0))
        contextDraw?.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)

        contextDraw?.setLineWidth(5.0)
        contextDraw?.move(to: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100))
        contextDraw?.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 150, y: 150))
        contextDraw?.strokePath()

        contextDraw?.restoreGState()

        guard let imgCg = contextDraw?.makeImage() else {
            return nil
        }
        imgViewPridict.image = UIImage.init(cgImage: imgCg)
        return contextDraw?.makeImage()

    }
```

You may need to inverse the content drawn on cgContext by applying AffineTransform to it.

Comment: Thanks you! that work!  when I move on screen that position of draw line not correct by that touch, how can I fix that?

Comment: Please do accept the answer if you find it helpful. And about the other thing you are asking. I don’t understand. Can you explain it a bit more. May be post that as a different question. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks so much for help, you saved my life, line is correct direction. how to draw it on uiimageview? I am drawing use my way but the line with finger not map,

Comment: You can set the image obtained from the function into your imageview. Say, imageview.image = image.

Comment: but that's not solve problem, that I used in above code